# Accessing custom constants in VB.NET as Build-Output

Tags: vb.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. In VB.NET-projects I can define custom constants in the compiler settings.

(How) Is it possible to refere to these constants in the project-settings? For instance I want to change to output path or the excutable name depending on the constant. If not is it possible to give the constants value to a postbuild-script?

Comment: This is really more of an MSBuild question than a VB question.  I'd add an MSBuild tag, but the edit queue is full.

Comment: Consider using MSBuild to modify the `.vbproj` file(project file). I believe you mean [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-compiler-settings-dialog-box-visual-basic?view=vs-2019), then it is saved in `.vbproj` file, for example `<DefineConstants>XXXX="XXX"</DefineConstants>`. Use [Condition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019) to write/add a condition in PropertyGroup. Use [$(<PropertyName>)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) to reference the property.